# Is there anyway to convince Zelazny to stand down?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

Heng Sha second visit: I'm on a mission (I believe it's called Talion AD) to convince Zelazny not to go a killing spree. Other than killing him, is there any way to stop him?

If not, what is the best way to complete this mission (ie. getting most experience)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the wiki, you can't reason with the guy. He's just too darn stubborn, and reasoning will only make him fight you.

You CAN, however, decide to approve of his actions, side with him, and then later lie to Dr. Wing about what happened, and you'll still get the quest reward.

Source: [Wikia: Talion A.D. page](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Talion_A.D.)

Comment: FYI: Your link links to a blank page.

Comment: You can also decide to approve of his actions, side with him and tell the truth to Dr. Wing, and you'll still get the kit.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer Unsure as to why it's blank, as the page does have content...unless I'm more tired than I think I am...

Comment: @Raven and Artless - the auto-convert-URL-to-link was ignoring the trailing `.` character. I've changed it to a manual reference link so it now works correctly.

Answer (score 4):

As Artless said, you can't reason with him. However, you don't have to kill him. A gas grenade is a particularly effective way of taking him and his men down non-lethally.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Artless's answer, you do not have to lie to Dr. Wing in order to complete this quest and get the Praxis kit, simply tell him the truth and use the 'convince'* option.

**I have the 'social enhancer' augmentation and do not know if it is required for this option to be available*